# openpyxl: a better way to read a range of numbers to an array

Tags: python, numpy, openpyxl

I am looking for a better (more readable / less hacked together) way of reading a range of cells using `openpyxl`. What I have at the moment works, but involves composing the excel cell range (e.g. `A1:C3`) by assembling bits of the string, which feels a bit rough.

At the moment this is how I read `nCols` columns and `nRows` rows starting from a particular cell (minimum working example, assumes that `worksheet.xlsx` is in working directory, and has the cell references written in cells `A1` to `C3` in `Sheet1`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np

firstCol = "B"
firstRow = 2

nCols = 2
nRows = 2

lastCol = chr(ord(firstCol) + nCols - 1) 

cellRange = firstCol + str(firstRow) + ":" + lastCol + str(firstRow + nRows - 1)

wsName = "Sheet1"
wb = load_workbook(filename="worksheet.xlsx", data_only=True)
data = np.array([[i.value for i in j] for j in wb[wsName][cellRange]])
print(data)
```

Returns:

```
[[u'B2' u'C2']
 [u'B3' u'C3']]
```

As well as being a bit ugly there are functional limitations with this approach. For example in sheets with more than 26 columns it will fail for columns like `AA`.

Is there a better/correct way to read `nRows` and `nCols` from a given top-left corner using openpyxl?

Comment: Do you really want to use openpyxl? Pandas has an excellent read_excel function which you can use to read the entire worksheet. Then use slicing to get the part you want.

Comment: Not particularly attached to `openpyxl`. It was what uncle google suggested when I asked about reading excel files from python. Will check out `pandas` and `read_excel`. Thanks for pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openpyxl provides functions for converting between numerical column indices (1-based index) and Excel's 'AA' style. See the `utils` module for details.

However, you'll have little need for them in general. You can use the `get_squared_range()` method of worksheets for programmatic access. And, starting with openpyxl 2.4, you can do the same with the `iter_rows()` and `iter_cols()` methods. NB. `iter_cols()` is not available in read-only mode.

The equivalent MWE using `iter_rows()` would be:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
wsName = "Sheet1"
wb = load_workbook(filename="worksheet.xlsx", data_only=True)
ws = wb[wsName]

firstRow = 2
firstCol = 2
nCols = 2
nRows = 2

allCells = np.array([[cell.value for cell in row] for row in ws.iter_rows()])

# allCells is zero-indexed
data = allCells[(firstRow-1):(firstRow-1+nRows),(firstCol-1):(firstCol-1+nCols)]
print(data)
```

The equivalent MWE using `get_squared_range()` would be:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np

wsName = "Sheet1"
wb = load_workbook(filename="worksheet.xlsx", data_only=True)

firstCol = 2
firstRow = 2
nCols = 2
nRows = 2

data = np.array([[i.value for i in j] for j in wb[wsName].get_squared_range(
            firstCol, firstRow, firstCol+nCols-1, firstRow+nRows-1)])
print(data)
```

Both of which return:

```
[[u'B2' u'C2']
 [u'B3' u'C3']]
```

See also https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/pandas.html for more information on using Pandas and openpyxl together.

Comment: Thanks. For completeness I've added the MWE using `get_squared_range(min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row)` to your answer.

Comment: It's best to concentrate on `iter_rows()` and `iter_cols()` as `get_squared_range()` is now deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll add the `iter_cols()` version of MWE to your answer as well.

Comment: Note that openpyxl 2.4 now explicitly supports Pandas' Dataframes.

Comment: link is dead for me, here's one that works: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html

Also, here's a link to utils.cell docs which includes coordinate conversions: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html

Answer (score 0):

For completeness (and so I can find it later) the equivalent code using the `pandas` function `read_excel` suggested by @Rob in a comment would be:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
wsName = "Sheet1"
df = pandas.read_excel(open("worksheet.xlsx", "rb"), sheetname=wsName, header=None)

firstRow = 2
firstCol = 2
nCols = 2
nRows = 2

# Data-frame is zero-indexed

data = np.array(df.ix[(firstRow-1):(firstRow-2+nRows), (firstRow-1):(firstRow-2+nRows)])
print(data)
```

Which returns:

```
[[u'B2' u'C2']
 [u'B3' u'C3']]
```

Comment: FWIW internally Pandas uses xlrd to read XLSX files which is fine but does not offer the memory optimisation of openpyxl's read-only mode. Unfortunately, however, as cells are stored as rows, you can't do simple conversion to columns...